# When uploading office document using content type, createdby/modified by is not showing as current user

Tags: document-library, content-type

This issue may look strange. I will try to explain in several steps.

1. I have one sharepoint online site with one document library and 4 content types associated to this document library. All content types are office documents.
2. I want to create one document by using associated content type to document library. So when I select the content type from the new dropdown, office document will open in my machine (Client machine).
3. I created document and saved back to library. For all the steps above I used **test1@mysite.com** account.
4. I followed the same steps to create one more document by using the **test2@mysite.com** in the same physical machine and saved back to the same document library.
5. Now if I see the document properties for the document2, eg., modified by, it is showing the **test1@mysite.com** account only. But in this case it should be **test2@mysite.com**.
6. If I remove the **test1@mysite.com** from the accounts in office document then it is asking for user name and password to open the document. But ideally client will not do this step all the time.

**Conclusion:**

How to open an office document (using content types) with the currently logged in user from the sharepoint site to local machine?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the word - word always saves files to sharepoint using the credentials of the user logged to the PC.
One solution is to use Web app server -  you don't mention the sharepoint version. Another to save it locally and upload it.

Comment: I mentioned as Sharepoint online.. so it will be 2013 version only :) Yeah agreed problem with the word.. There is no solution for this?

Comment: You are right about sp 2013. I had a conversation with an MS guy about removing the ability to log on as different user. Among other problems, I remember saying about Word saves.